# Invoke java silently, Mac Os X

Tags: java, macos, console, operating-system

I have a huge generated shell script with a lot of lines like

```
java -jar <app_jar> <params>
```

Every invocation brings a java icon to the dock, making active application to loose the focus every line where java app is invoked

Is there a way to run it silently?

Java application is a single class, simple console app with a file IO routines, no windows created whatsoever

Comment: Have you tried `java -jar <app_jar> <params> &` to run the process in the background?

Comment: Not really relevant, but if you are starting up JVMs over and over again, you might be paying a significant performance penalty...

Comment: It is an off-line processing stage, obviously not meant to be used in realtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [oracle's doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html), the following should work:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true
```